# CultureInfo in C#

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

My system is id-ID, using ',' as decimal separator. I have problems with data in en-US, I want to convert it to id-ID and then back to en-US :

```
 List<string> list = new List<string>(){"0.14","223.54"}; // en-US

 list[0] = Convert.ToDecimal(list[0], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString();
 MessageBox.Show("list[0] = " + list[0]); //display "0,14", it is ok!
 MessageBox.Show("list[1] = " + list[1]); //display "223,54", it is ok!
```

Now I want to change it back to US culture, I can simply use Replace to change ',' back to '.' as US culture.

```
 MessageBox.Show("list[0] = " + list[0].Replace(",", ".")); //displays  "0.14"
```

But it is not an elegant way to handle it, I wish I can handle it with CultureInfo, so I try the following statements but can't work!

```
 CultureInfo us = new CultureInfo("en-US");
 list[0] = Convert.ToDecimal(list[0], us).ToString();
 list[1] = Convert.ToDecimal(list[1], us).ToString();
 MessageBox.Show("list[0] = " + list[0]); //display "14", the decimal separator is missing!
 MessageBox.Show("list[1] = " + list[1]); //display "223,54", nothing changed!
```

Answer (score 1):

en-US culture uses comma as a number group separator. This a reason of the mistake.
Better approach is to store decimal as decimal. Use required culture when you output data:

```
List<string> stringList = new List<string>() { "0.14", "223.54" };
List<decimal> list = stringList.Select(Convert.ToDecimal).ToList();

MessageBox.Show(list[0].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
MessageBox.Show(list[0].ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US")));
MessageBox.Show(list[0].ToString(new CultureInfo("id-ID")));
```

Comment: Thank you, your example works ok, but how about the data are strings?

Comment: @xpw: You should convert input strings to decimals and work with decimals not strings. I edit answer to show the approach

Comment: yes, the raw data is string, so I first convert string to decimal, and hope it will be in correct culture format, and it failed as you can see in my examples.

Comment: You could add validation logic to be sure that input data are valid. But that's another story.

Comment: if(decimal.TryParse(list[0], out d))

Comment: yes, I have use statement as above to check the validity, and it is sure another story.